# Как вывести посты из под категории в wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть список под категорий выведенных на странице при клике должны выводится посты данной поддиректории, без перезагрузки страницы. Сказали, что можно сделать через WP_Query().

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я вывел на страницу имена категорий, нужно что-бы при клике на них ниже показывались статьи из этой категории без перезагрузки страницы

Answer (score 2):

Если страниц мало (и их контента), то можно собирать контент в невидимый блок и по клику показывать то, что нужно (запрашивать страницы из базы действительно с помощью WP_Query)

Если страниц много, то подгружать контент без перезагрузки страниц поможет AJAX. Рекомендую написать плагин, который будет обрабатывать действие `wp_ajax_` Почитать можно [тут](http://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html) и, естественно, в [кодексе](http://codex.wordpress.org)